# Will the transaction process eventually become easier?

Tags: transaction, wallet

I’ve heard a lot of good things about IOTA and I myself am quite convinced about the technology. However right now we read a lot about stuck transactions and that we have to promote and reattach for days. What would approaches be for wallets that don’t need all that? Where we just hit send and the funds are being send to another address? Because if we don’t achieve that I doubt that we will get a high user acceptance. Are there any approaches?

Comment: That's quite the invitation for guessing, which doesn't pair well with the Stack Exchange Q&A concept. Please have a look at the [tour] to learn more about SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A transaction is not valid until it is directly or indirectly referenced by the coordinator. To get validated by the coordinator, other transactions have to reference yours. Clicking send and having your funds sent is currently only possible in flash channels (basically IOTAs lightning network), which are still in beta yet.

Sometimes, however, transactions get orphaned and don't get referenced anymore, as newer transactions are more likely to be picked. These orphaned transactions will never get confirmed

The current approach is, that you can promote your transaction. This adds a 0-value transaction referencing yours. As this transaction is newer when it is broadcasted (the Proof of Work is faster), it's more likely to get picked and indirectly approving your transaction.

As the network scales, there will be fewer orphans as there are more transactions. Also, there might be a better algorithm to choose transactions to reference.

Answer (score 0):

"right now we read a lot" -- It is important to remember that people rarely write about successful transactions but do complain when things go wrong. I have done many transactions, to/from exchanges, between wallets of mine, to tip people etc. but the only time I wrote anything about it on slack or elsewhere was after a snapshot when I was sure I had attached enough addresses to see my balancethen got worried (I was two attachements away from seeing it but complained first). Not to say there is not room for improvements with this "beta" phase (there is and they have been coming) but the issues are greatly exaggerated IMO.